# How dropdownlist bind with slqdatasource retrieve proper value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Well I want to retrieve the value from the dropdown list to write for my .cs. The sqldatasource returns either Saving Account or Current account depending on what kind of account type does he/she have.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPayBy2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="accountType" 
                            DataValueField="accountType">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Oakhorizons %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [accountType] FROM [SavingAccount] WHERE ([custID] = @custID)">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="OH00002" Name="custID" 
                                    SessionField="Session[&quot;custID&quot;]" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Well it's been returning me nothing. I've tried this but nothing is returned. I always get the else statement and I tried to debug and it says SelectedValue = ""

```
 if (ddlPayBy.SelectedValue == "Savings"){
          account = "Savings";
                                    }
 else if (ddlPayBy.SelectedValue == "Current")
                                    {
          account = "Current";
                                    }
 else
                                    {
          Alert.Show("Please choose your account type properly");
                                    }
```

Comment: try with `SessionField="custID"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i haven't used the sqldatasource object in awhile so forgive me, but are you missing something simple like not binding the control to the datasource object.

Perhaps your parameter isn't being set properly. Do you have access to SQL Profiler? Check and see if your query is running and running with the right query ...

also a side note ... this prob isn't it but your  dropdown's id ="ddlPayBy2" but you're checking if (ddlPayBy.selected....